# Why VC++ IntelliSense doesn't refresh error list?

Tags: visual-studio

Why VC++ IntelliSense doesn't refresh error list?

There's an error in the code. IntelliSense shows it up. I fix it, and press F7 to re-compile, the compilation result is successful. But now IntelliSense doesn't refresh the error list, it still shows the former error, even after pressing 10 times F7 and F5 to start debugging.

That crazy IntelliSense error is still shown up. What happened with VC++?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  Also, did you try to delete the IntelliSense file from your project directory?  Close your VS solution, delete the file, and re-open and re-compile the solution to generate it again.

Comment: What version of Visual Studios? And what Edition?

Comment: vs2010, i had to wait a few minutes for it to refresh the error list, or must close and re-open the project